# Meu wamp não funciona

Tags: dll, wampserver

Preciso baixar o composer, porém preciso do wampserver, mas o wamp não está abrindo pois sempre falta uma dll. Antes era a 100, depois foi a 110, e depois foi a 120.

Eu baixei cada dll, fui no site da Microsoft, baixei o Visual C++, fiz tudo, mas toda vez que instalo o wampserver, ele dá o mesmo erro. Tentei utilizar o composer pelo Easyphp Devserver, porém o composer dá erro na instalação do Easyphp. Tem que ser com o wampserver, porém não consigo fazer ele funcionar.

Já fui reiniciar várias vezes e atualizou o Windows várias vezes mas não deu em nada, continuou o mesmo erro.

Alguém aqui tem o link de algum site onde eu possa baixar o wampserver completo zipado para que não dê esse erro?

Comment: [site oficial](http://www.wampserver.com)

Comment: Mas eu tinha baixado lá mesmo, só que sempre dá a mesma coisa, o meu sistema é 64 bits, eu to baixando sempre o wamp para 64 bits, isso tem alguma coisa haver?

Comment: Não deveria, já desinstalou e instalou de novo, excluindo TUDO referente ao wamp? alguma coisa que tu deixou passar pode estar atrapalhando a reinstalação

Comment: Já, só que é sempre a mesma coisa, acho que desabilitei alguma parada no gerenciador de tarefas, o problema é que não tá habilitando td, os que eu habilito só fizeram o erro que dava ao invés de ser 120dll, é 110dll agr, mas já si mais ou menos o que fazer agr, vlw manin